# Way to scroll up and scroll down an xml object

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

See it first: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSgWY.jpg

For now I have the scroll of the button and the scroll of the button clicking the a button with `view.animate().translationY(float);`
But this is an animation and it's not scrolled by the finger. 
Any ideas?

Comment: the view needs to be inside a scrollable view like scrollview for touch based scrolling

Comment: You need to move the smiles container, right?

Comment: @Manza Yes, but the button must be visible on the bottom of the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is two ways:

1. Add onTouchListener and watch ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP events. In DOWN you need to remember touch position, then in MOVE calculate current difference between start position and current. And in UP same with MOVE.
2. Place your view inside of HorizontalScrollView and system will handle scrolling by itself.